How can I show PDF file on click notification in Kotlin?
The next NotificationUtil helps me to show the notification with PDF file, but when I click on notification and select the PDF viewer, it shows me the next message: 'You can not open file'.
object NotificationUtil {
    private const val CHANNEL_ID = "download_notification_channel"
    private var NOTIFICATION_ID = 123

    fun showNotification(context: Context, file: File, typeFile: String) {
        val channel = NotificationChannel(
            CHANNEL_ID,
            "Descargas",
            NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT
        )
        val notificationManager = context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel)

        // Get URI
        val fileUri = Uri.fromFile(file)

        val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
        intent.setDataAndType(fileUri, typeFile)
        intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)

        val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT)

        // Build notification
        val builder = NotificationCompat.Builder(context, CHANNEL_ID)
            .setContentTitle(file.name)
            .setContentText("Se completó la descarga")
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.download)
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setAutoCancel(true)

        // Show notification
        notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID++, builder.build())
    }
}

I would like to open PDF file when I click on the notification.

Utilizing the Android FileProvider, I was able to open the PDF file I created, which resolved my issue.

thank you bro, i did some changes in my notificationUtil with FileProvider. @Crebain
